# Windows Workflow: Percentage Complete

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I want to display a progress bar in my WPF application for the overall completion of my main workflow.

At first glance this doesn't seem possible. Is there a method or way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I would like to show the percentage of completed tasks.

Comment: A percentage of what? The amount of time? The amount of finished activities? Do you include loops?

Comment: @Maarten I would like to show the percentage of tasks completed. As to loops or other control statements, these are what I'm unsure of on how to handle. When I couldn't find any obvious native way to do get percentage complete of tasks I thought I could somehow navigate through the workflow, get the number of tasks, and then tick off the completed ones as they finished.

Comment: Something tells me your workflows probably complete within a second or two, making the effort to accomplish this less than worthless.

Comment: @Will, no they do not. The actual use of this workflow is for multiple component installations. Each component defines a workflow of how to accomplish its install. These workflows are then aggregated and executed. Each component takes between 3-5 minutes to complete with a total time of around ~8 minutes. The user needs to get feedback on progress. Potential components may take up to 30 minutes to complete.

Comment: @MikeG: Okay, that's good.  So, do you have a custom activity for installing a component, or kicking off the component installation?  If so, you can use a workflow extension to communicate outside the workflow what is going on, and from that update the users.

Comment: @Will, yes I do. I already have an extension to communicate current task and any information that the task may log. What I'm trying to do is have a progress bar show a % of steps finished. I understand that control logic could make a scenario where the progress went from 3% to 80% just because an if statement caused a large portion of the workflow to not execute.

Comment: @MikeG: Well, I can tell you that the closest you may find would be debugging info (WAG); But there really isn't any concept for "activity 1 of 217 is executing now" in WF.  Perhaps add in custom "update" activities?  There might be a way to tally their number during CacheMetadata, then as they go along they can yell out of the workflow when they are hit...  At this point, your guess is as good as mine.